# How to make a drop down button float along side of a list item using html & css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

please have a look at the attached image. [image]

What I want to do is align the drop down button to be aligned (something like it will overlap on the items following the 1st list item) with the first item of the repeating list. I can do it by adding the drop down button in a column inside repeating list, but in that case the gap between 1st & 2nd items got very large. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

I am using HTML, CSS Bootstrap

**Edit**
The code is large thats why I choose not to provide it on the 1st go. However, here it is:

```
<div class="packaging-task-section">

    <div class="row packaging-items-header" style="margin-left: 1px;">
        <div class="col-md-2 small-padding-right-only">
            <label class="control-label">Item</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 small-padding-right-only">
            <label class="control-label">Unit</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 small-padding-right-only">
            <label class="control-label">No Of Unit</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 small-padding-right-only">
            <label class="control-label">Unit Cost</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 small-padding-right-only">
            <label class="control-label">Unit Sell</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 small-padding-right-only">
            <label class="control-label">Total Sell</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 table-condensed table-packaging nopadding padding-right-5">
            <div class="pull-right margin-top-10" style="width: 185px; margin-right: 8px;">
                some control
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in someList" class="handle-package-item row" style="margin-left: 2px;">

        <div class="col-md-2 small-padding-right-only">
            custom directive
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign form-control-feedback right-5-top-5" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 small-padding-right-only">
            <input class="form-control  input-sm  handle-package-task-item-unit-{{$index}}" data-ng-disabled="true" data-ng-model="packageTaskItem.unitName" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 small-padding-right-only">
            <input type="text" class="form-control  input-sm handle-package-task-item-no-{{$index}} padding-right-0"
                   data-ng-model="packageTaskItem.numberOfUnits"
                   ng-change="method()" only-digitals />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 small-padding-right-only">
            <input class="form-control handle-package-task-item-cost-{{$index}} input-sm" data-ng-disabled="true" data-ng-model="packageTaskItem.cost" money-value />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 small-padding-right-only">

            <div class="col-md-12 nopadding input-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-dollar"></i>
                <input money-value placeholder="0.00" data-ng-disabled="!packageTaskItem.packagingItemKey" name="packaging-item-sell-{{$index}}"
                       class="form-control  handle-package-task-item-sell-{{$index}} padding-right-0 input-sm"
                       min="0" data-ng-model=" packageTaskItem.sell" />
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 small-padding-right-only">

            <input required class="form-control input-sm" disabled data-ng-model="packageTaskItem.itemTotalSell" money-value />

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 small-padding-right-only">
            <div class="checkbox-inline">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="font-red handle-package-item-remove">
                    <i class="fa fa-times font-icon"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="table-condensed table-packaging row nopadding padding-right-5">
        <div class="col-md-7 small-padding-right-only" style="display: table-cell;">
            <label class="control-label pull-right bold">Total Amount</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 small-padding-right-only" style="display: table-cell;">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="width: auto;">
                <input class="form-control input-sm" value="" disabled data-ng-model="vm.packagingTotal" money-value />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 small-padding-right-only" style="display: table-cell;">
            <label class="pull-right bold">Actual Charge</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 small-padding-right-only" style="display: table-cell;">
            <div class="col-md-12 nopadding input-icon right">
                some custom directive
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="clearfix">
</div>
```

**Edit 2**
Where the gap between 1st and 2nd row (or as in the 1st image, header & 1st row) will not be affected by the height of the drop down.
[image]

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: what you really needed?are you want to merge the drop down item with the first row?

Comment: @dreamhunter sorry for the delay. Yes I want to add the drop down with 1st row in such a way that the dropdown will seems to be overlapping between following rows. Please refer to the newly added image.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but you are using the `label` tag incorectly : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label